# Returning flow type from redux reducer not catching error

Tags: react-native, react-redux, flowtype

I have a flow type `UserState` which I'm defining as the return type for a reducer. I added an additional `hey` prop to the return type and am not getting an error. I would have expected a `Property not found in object type` Anyways, If anyone knows if I am doing something wrong, I'd love to hear it. Thanks.

```
type UserState = {
  +female?: boolean,
}

const user = (state: UserState = {}, action: ReduxFetchUserAction): UserState => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case types.FETCH_USER_SUCCESS: {
      const newUser = { ...state, ...action.user, hey: 'whatgives' }
      return newUser
    }
    default:
      return state
  }
}

export default user
```

Comment: `hey` isn't in the `UserState` type?

Comment: Yes, you are right, `hey` is not in `UserState` so I thought flow would complain that the hey property is not in the object.